# Are there any natural theories T for which P=NP implies T proves P=NP?

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity

The qualifier "natural" is meant to exclude examples like "PA + P=NP" or "PA + True $\Pi_1$".
For concreteness, let's say that "natural" = sound, computably enumerable, with a feasible proof-checker.

*Context of the question.*

A naive way to approach the P vs NP problem, from the logical point of view, could go like this:

1. Show that if P=NP, then P=NP is provable is some fixed system $S$, such as ZFC or ZFC+large cardinals;
2. Improve the previous result for weaker and weaker $S$ $-$ for example, go from ZFC down to PA2, PA, $I\Sigma_1$, etc.;
3. Once $S$ is as elementary as possible, use an ad-hoc argument to show $\not \vdash_S$ P=NP.

Of course, as all known approaches to the problem, this one quickly falls upon itself.

**Proposition.** (*folklore?*)
For every function $f$ which is computed by a Turing machine $M$, and for every natural formal system $S$, which proves that $M$ computes $f$, there exists a Turing machine $M'$ which computes $f$, such that $S$ does not prove that $M'$ computes $f$.  The runtime of $M'$ is $O(n+Time(M))$.

Given input $x$, the machine $M'$ searches for a contradiction in $S$ for $|x|$ many steps. If no contradiction is found, it runs $M$ on $x$, returning the result; otherwise, it launches all nuclear missiles at once.

Of course, $M'$ computes $f$.  But $S$ can never know this, because then it would know that there is no contradiction from $S$, contradicting Gödel's theorem.

The point of the above observation is that no formal system can make inferences about correctness of algorithms from runtime constraints alone. If we assume that S knows that some machine M decides SAT in polynomial time, there will always be another M for which S will not know this.

*Motivation.*

This seems troubling, since it can in principle be conceived that, while P=NP, the logical complexity of proving any polynomial-time satisfiability algorithm $M$ to be correct can be larger than the consistency strength of any formal theory $T$ that may be considered in say, the next 100 years:

$(\forall x\ M(x){\in}\{0,1\}\ \&\ (M(x)=1 \iff x \in SAT)) \Rightarrow \mathsf{Con}(T)$

Can such a situation be ruled out, for some natural extension $T$ of ZFC?  This would mean exactly that $T$ answers the question posed in the title.

Comment: Trivially,  "P=NP implies T proves P=NP" holds if we parse it as  P=NP implies (T proves P=NP). So I guess that you mean  (P=NP implies T) proves P=NP.

Comment: I mean the former.  If you have the answer, please share it.  Even (and especially!) if it seems trivial. ;)

Comment: By elementary logic, if we premise a proposition $A$ (e.g. P=NP), then any theory whatsoever, including (say) ZFC + $\lnot A$, can prove $A$: Just write down any true statements of the theory you like (or none, if you prefer); then introduce $A$; and $A$ follows immediately.

Comment: Counterexample.T=PA. A=Con(PA).

Comment: Of course, PA does not prove Con(PA) if we can include no assumption beyond PA in any proof. But this stricture entails that the "$A$ implies" (i.e. Con(PA) implies) part of the statement is without any force and is effectively redundant. So, returning to the original question, what exactly do you mean by "P=NP implies"?

Comment: Also false.  If A is the negation of Goldbach's conjecture, then PA proves A, "without including any assumption beyond PA" in the proof.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand you now: If ¬GC holds, then simply checking GC/¬GC for the individual cases 4, 6, etc.---a purely PA process---will eventually terminate and so constitute a proof of ¬GC purely within PA. The rules of your "$A$ implies" seem to be that we may posit $A$ to draw from it information about what kind of proofs are possible within $T$, but no reference to $A$ as an assumable statement may be made within any $T$-based proof. Please explain if this interpretation is unclear, imprecise, or wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49528/discussion-between-andrew-polonsky-and-john-bentin).

Comment: I think this is basically asking whether $\text{P} \neq \text{NP}$ is equivalent to any $\Pi_1$ sentence.  This is [non-trivially the case with RH](https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/grytczuk.pdf) for example, so if RH is false then PA proves that.  There is [an article about this subject](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/arithmetic-hierarchy-and-pnp/) on Dick Lipton's blog that you may be interested in.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work? Use the [Bellantoni-Cook theorem](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sacook/homepage/ptime.pdf%20Bellantoni-Cook%20theorem) to enumerate all the polynomial time Turing machines.  If P=NP you will eventually run into a machine that you can recognize as running Levin's universal search algorithm on some NP-complete problem.  That proves Levin's algorithm on that problem runs in P-time and therefore P=NP.  The paper also cites a result of Leviant that

> a function is polytime if and only if it can be proved convergent in the logical system $L_2(QF^+)$ using the function’s recursion equations and a 'surjective' principle.  Here $L_2(QF^+)$ is second order logic with comprehension (i.e., definability of sets) for positive quantifier-free fomulas.

which might be of use to you.

(Hmm, I don't know if the BC theorem actually lets you enumerate the P-time Turing machines, or just syntactic descriptions of the languages, that might not get you all the recognizers.  I better read the paper more carefully).

Comment: No, this doesn't work, for exactly the reason you state. It's not possible to enumerate polynomial-time Turing machines in the way you are suggesting - telling if a fixed Turing machine halts in polynomial time - as this would enable you to solve the halting problem by considering Turing machines that ignore their input and hence either halt in constant time or run forever.